# Get system icon

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

A simple question.
How do I get these system icons?

[image]

I use this interface:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676973(v=vs.85).aspx

SHGetStockIconInfo function uses enum SHSTOCKICONID where there are these icons.
Can you tell me please id these icons?

Comment: The [MSDN Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762542(v=vs.85).aspx) for SHSTOCKICONID actually shows the icons ... The ones you want are resources in objsel.dll (at least on win7).

Comment: What do you mean "get" them? What do you wish to do with them?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `SIID_USERS`? That would appear to be the one you want.